# REST API, Querying Lookup Additional column giving error

Tags: rest

I have an additional lookup column `RelatedLinks:Title`. I am not able to query using rest api. Getting - The field or property `RelatedLinks_x003a_Title` does not exist. What is the proper way to select additional lookup column ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$expand` feature as follows

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items?$expand=RelatedLinks&select=RelatedLinks/Title
```

Comment: Thanks Amal Hashim. It is working for normal lookup columns. But not for Additional Lookup columns. Any idea, how to mention additional lookup columns that have ':' in their name?

Comment: @PradeepNulu have you tried adding the additional columns to the select?

Comment: I am getting the above error while adding the additional columns to the select